# Using Arduino to show images in Serial Monitor

Tags: sensors, arduino-ide

Some time ago I came across a Vedic in which a person has hacked an optical mouse's camera and displayed the image in the Serial Monitors.
My question:
How to use Serial Monitor to display an image captured by the Arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this guide](http://frenki.net/2013/12/convert-optical-mouse-into-arduino-web-camera/), he doesn't actually display the images on the serial monitor, only the image data for each pixel.

Then another program (Javascript and some HTML) on the PC side collects the data and converts it to a greyscale image.

Comment: If you happen to know, could you tell me how _those_  programs work